ORIGAMI: Above and beyond
It's been a long time since I've posted an origami puzzle!
An origami puzzle is solved with some thickness $x$ iff it can be folded into a rectangle (possibly a square) with thickness $x$ everywhere.
Identify a puzzle in the official ORIGAMI PUZZLES that can be solved with some thickness $t'$ that is a non-trivial factor of its labeled thickness $t$ (that is, $t'|t$ and $t'\ne t$) and solve it as such.
Although solutions are not required to be applicable in real life, using an actual sheet of paper is a great visualization tool.
A puzzle for this type of orgami puzzle game made by Ωmega_3301, similar to this question.

I can fold #14 to thickness 5, #25 to 5, #26 to 7, #27 to 11 and #29 to 12.  Does it count as trivial?

How does that answer my question?


 $t = 4$, $t' = 2$:

Found this when originally solving the first few example puzzles.

Intended, well done
